# What does d3.range.map do?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

Given the following code:

```
var num = 20;
var points = d3.range(num).map(function(d) {
  return {
    x: spread(d),
    y: Math.floor(Math.random() * (height)
  }
});
```

Can someone please explain to me what `d3.range.map` is doing here? Specifically, what is `d` here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's mapping each value from the created range to an object, so `d` refers to each value from the range in turn.

More specifically, `d3.range(num)` will create an array of integers from 0 to 19, so `[0, 1, 2, ..., 18, 19]`. See [here](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/README.md#range) for more information on `d3.range`.

When `.map` is called on the array we access each value in turn through the callback function. In the example this is the parameter `d`. So `d` will have the value `0`, then `1`, etc. up to `19`. Information on array mapping can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

The callback function is then returning an object for each value in the array. So the variable `points` will be an array containing objects with an `x` and `y` property.